# Little window showing zoomed contents near the brush while holding specific key

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts, zoom

I am looking for the following feature in Photoshop (natively or as a plugin):

When you press and hold down the specific key, a little window will appear at the corner what shows the zoomed content of the area where your brush is currently at. The window updates it’s contents as you move your brush, following it of course. The window will disappear as soon as you let go of the key you were holding. The feature is available with any tool, at any time. With this feature you don’t have to constantly zoom in and out to get the pixel-perfect precision when it’s necessary.

Answer (score 2):

There is a built in tool in photoshop called **Navigator**

Click **Window** then choose **Navigator**

Comment: You completely misunderstood me. That is far from something I requested.

Comment: @FadeyAnomaly Husam's answer is a perfectly valid alternative, although it doesn't function exactly the way you suggest, the Navigator window can be used very effectively for [detailed retouching](https://imgur.com/a/Myr6l) reducing the need to zoom in and out of an image.